# Deactivating Camera flash causes app to crash

Tags: android, android-camera

I am having trouble in handling camera flash app crashes. When I activate flash for the first time it clicks the image but to try again **after deactivating** the camera app gets crashed.

Here is my code I have taken a simple button on which click listener is applied and `actionFlash()` is called. I couldn't find error in the code.

These two functions are called from `actionFlash()` :

```
public void turnOnFlashLight()
{
    try
    {
        flashof.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_flash_on_black_24dp);
        mCaptureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CameraMetadata.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        mPreviewCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mCaptureRequestBuilder.build(), null, null);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Flash activated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Flash failed:\n" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

public void turnOffFlashLight()
{
    try
    {
        flashof.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_flash_off_black_24dp);
        mCaptureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CameraMetadata.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        mPreviewCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mCaptureRequestBuilder.build(), null, null);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Flash disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Flash failed:\n" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

**actionFlash() is called on the button click**

```
private void actionFlash()
{
    hasFlash = this.getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);
    if (!hasFlash) {
        AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        alert.setMessage("Sorry, your device doesn't support flash light!");
        alert.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        alert.show();
        return;
    }
    else {  
        CameraManager mCameraManager = (CameraManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            String mCameraId = mCameraManager.getCameraIdList()[1];
            if (mCameraId.equals("1")) {    
                if (!isFlashOn) {                         
                    turnOnFlashLight();                        
                    isFlashOn = true;             
                    flashof.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_flash_off_black_24dp);
                } else {                         
                    turnOffFlashLight();
                    isFlashOn = false;                       flashof.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_flash_on_black_24dp);
                }
            }
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Cannot access the camera.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            this.finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the error log? Difficult to debug without knowing the reason it is crashing.

Comment: No Nic it is not posting any error for the first time when I activate it works properly then after one click when I deactivate the flash complete app freezes doesn't works anything No error comes I tried debugging but I couldn't find any proper solution for this

Comment: if your app is crashing then it will be producing a crash Stack trace. Look at the Android Monitor tab of android studio when it crashes and copy the stacktrace into your question

Comment: Nic I have copied the problem do check what am missing to resolve it

Comment: Please edit your question rather than post an answer with changes to your post. Can you also filter your log to show the actual stack trace?

Comment: Look in your android monitor screen. Set the filter to your app only. Perform the actions that cause your app to crash. Look for the stacktrace for the crash `Fatal Exception in .....`. Once you have that, click edit on your question and post it in there. I don't know how much clearer I can make it.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you unless you can find the correct stacktrace.